# Read feature flag from toml in Maud HTML to show/hide div

Tags: html, rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, rust-warp

I have a feature flag to enable disable feature in rust web application(Using Maud HTML), I want to use the feature flag toggle inside Maud HTML to show/hide div?

In below scenario, div block should enable and display role related contents only if flag is set as administrator or editor respectively.

Implemented below code but is not working as expected irrespective of the flag set in cargo.toml and also no errors as well. Please help here on how to use feature flag check inside a maud HTML appropriately.

**EDIT** - This is working fine as i made syntax issue in maud by missing braces and also added else condition as div.none which is not required

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
maud = "0.21.0"


[features]
administrator = []
reader=[]
default = ["reader"]
```

**main.rs**

```
use maud::html;
use maud::Markup;

fn main() {
    let htmlcontent = render_html();
    println!("Html content:{}", htmlcontent.into_string())
}

pub fn render_html() -> Markup {
 html! {
    @if cfg!(feature = "administrator")  {
       div.block {
         // TODO: Administrator related UI controls
       }
    } @else if cfg!(feature = "reader") {
       div.block {
         // TODO: Reader related UI controls
      }
    } 
 }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? An error please add the message? A discrepancy in output vs what you expect, describe expected and actual output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.